# C++ class Matriz - Matriz c; c[3, 5]

Tags: c++, c++11

Declarad y definid para cada una de las siguientes sentencias A, B, y C que haría falta añadir a una clase Matriz (implementada mediante un doble puntero a enteros) para que funcionasen correctamente.

```
int main(){
    Matriz c;
    /*A*/ c[3,5]; //devuelve el elto. En la pos. 3,5
    /*B*/ c[3][5]; // idem
    /*C*/ c(3,5); // idem
   return (0);
};
```

Por más vueltas que le he dado no logro soucionar el apartado /*A*/ c[3,5]; lo he intentado como una sobrecarga de operator[], y también como sobrecarga de operator, pero en ambos casos me da error

```
std::cout << "C[3, 5] = " << c[3,5] << std::endl;
```

Quería poner todo el código que tengo pero me dice que la pregunta es básicamente código y no me deja enviar.

El caso B y C los tengo hechos, el C mediante la sobrecarga del operator(), el B mediante la sobrecarga del operator[] que devuelve un objeto a una clase anidada, la cual igualmente por sobrecarga del operator[] develve la matriz completa.

El problema es el método que identifique c[3, 5]; me hace pensar en un typedef del operator [] a () pero lo que he intentado no me ha salido, no creo que eso sea posuble ¿o sí?, ¿alguna indicación de como podría ser el método que identifique c[3, 5]?

Comment: Pues sin el código, poco se podrá hacer. ¿ Has consultado lo que es un [mcve] ? No es necesario todo el código que tengas; solo **lo mínimo** para reproducir el problema.

Comment: He editado la pregunta

Comment: En [tag:c++], no existen sobrecargas del operador corchetes (`[]`) que acepte dos parámetros.

Comment: El problema es identificar que dentro del corchete hay dos valores, estaba pensando en una función lambda tipo:

Comment: El problema es identificar que dentro del corchete hay dos valores, estaba pensando en una función lambda tipo: auto lamb = [this](int fil, int col)->int {return matriz[fil][col]; } dentro de la función operator[], el problema es capturar col, porque salta el error de que en c[3, 5] el operador izquierdo y la coma no tienen efecto

Comment: El problema no se soluciona con lambdas, porque las lambdas son objetos función libres y no puedes asociarlos a un operador. En [tag:c++] no existen sobrecargas del operador corchetes que acepte dos parámetros, por mucha brujería que intentes.

Comment: Pero es el eneunciado de un ejercicio con nota, debe de ser posible hacerlo, ¿como capturar los valores del elemento del objeto c[3, 5], es decir, al escribir c[3, 5] debe devolver el elemento de matriz[3][5], ¿alguna forma de hacer que c[3, 5] funcione como si hubieras escrito c(3, 5)?

Comment: El enunciado puede decir misa, pero no se puede.

Comment: @Torkan cuando el profesor os de la respuesta a este problema, deberías compartirla con la comunidad para ver qué es lo que era.

Comment: La respuesta correcta era que no se puede programar en C++ nada como c[3, 5], dado que el operador [] no se puede sobrecargar como una función friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), no existen sobrecargas del operador corchetes (`[]`) que acepte más de un parámetro.

No puedes sobrecargar el operador coma internamente:

```
template <typename T, unsigned X, unsigned Y>
struct Matriz
{
    T &operator,(unsigned c)
    { return datos[c / Y][c % X]; }
    T datos[Y][X]{};
};
```

Porque eso implica que la matriz tiene que estar al lado izquierdo de la expresión...

```
using m3x3 = Matriz<int, 3u, 3u>;

m3x3 m{1u, 2u, 3u, 4u, 5u, 6u, 7u, 8u, 9u};

std::cout << (m , 2u);
//           ^^^^^^^ <--- T &Matriz::operator,
```

... no dentro de los corchetes. Tampoco lo puedes sobrecargar externamente para generar un objeto coordenadas, ya que no se permite sobrecargar operadores para tipos fundamentales:

```
std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> operator,(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
    return {x, y};
}
```

> ```
> error: ‘std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> operator,(unsigned int, unsigned int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
>  std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> operator,(unsigned x, unsigned y)
>                                                                ^
> ```

[Tu única opción](https://tio.run/##VU/LboMwEDzjr1ipakIUojZJnwnhD3rLIRH1wTIusoQNMmspFOXXSxdom0byyKvZnZldWVWLXMquu9FWFj5TEOuyRqeESdiF86gLjU3CGCpTFQKJw6ZSVhgF@wi8rXVuVQaHf/UxYeTkJcKbQKc/WcuCPUzKSjmBpYvCv0k5Y0ELTqF3FjJq1qmEOzhy@m7hwLdwvpKmPJSlrRFqzDabSmgX/3pd8hOYDL4sCITHEtJTBA2HHcgtUVdhDU9PnNghZaQo@8Db85bRY9oiGKFtOOtv8LW2OZj1aU1m42kxTUSw9j0SEgRD17RLYlZ@7DwQHglPhGfCC@HV9/bBcIYsPUIcQ2igF836evpup7QsVSZtlxEsz7yf/1n@nrbrui/5UYi87hbkspPz@Up8Aw) es sobrecargar el operador corchetes para recibir un objeto coordenadas:

```
template <typename T, unsigned X, unsigned Y>
struct Matriz
{
    T &operator,(unsigned c)
    { return datos[c / Y][c % X]; }
    T &operator[](const std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> &c)
    {
        auto [x, y] = c;
        return datos[y][x];
    }
    T datos[Y][X]{};
};

int main()
{
    using m3x3 = Matriz<int, 3u, 3u>;

    m3x3 m{1u, 2u, 3u, 4u, 5u, 6u, 7u, 8u, 9u};

    std::cout << (m , 2u) << '\n'
        << m[{1, 1}];
    //       ^^^^^^ <--- Objeto coordenadas.
    return 0;
}
```

Da igual lo que diga el enunciado, en C++ no se puede programar nada como `c[3, 5]`.

Comment: Quizá sea justo esa la respuesta en esa parte del ejercicico, que no es posible esa expresión.